# Can I get a captured image from the Android device information screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, device, capture, info

```
Intent setting = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);
```

You can display the Android device information screen with the above code.

But when I run the code that captures the screen and saves the image, I get nothing.

I think this is for security reasons, but I need that feature. Is it possible in another way?

```
private void takeScreenshot(View v1) {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

        try {
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the capture code I tried.

```
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

put the above code

```
v1.getDrawingCache()
```

I don't get anything from the above code.

All actions should be performed automatically, without click events such as buttons.

Comment: I think your code just take screenshot of your app. If you want to take screenshot from other apps, you need to use service or something like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per my understanding you want to take screenshot of screen , so try below code,

in xml ,
step 1)

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Click on button to take screenshot"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/clickme"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:text="Click Me" />
```

and in activity step 2) initiate button and call onclick and add below,

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You just Captured a Screenshot," + Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        screenshot(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), "result");

        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

step 3) declare screenshot function,

```
protected static File screenshot(View view, String filename) {
    Date date = new Date();

// Here we are initialising the format of our image name
    CharSequence format = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", date);
    try {
// Initialising the directory of storage
        String dirpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "";
        File file = new File(dirpath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            boolean mkdir = file.mkdir();
        }

// File name
        String path = dirpath + "/" + filename + "-" + format + ".jpeg";
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        File imageurl = new File(path);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageurl);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        return imageurl;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

step 4) most remember point ask user to storage permission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE). hope it's help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

I'm sorry, but I think I'm missing some content.
The action should be automatic without any button event.
Is it possible?

Comment: yes, to work auto, call button click grammatically and hide button OR onCreate call function directly.